# Row Reduction with indexed parameters in GNU APL

Tags: data-structures, gnu, fold, apl

I'm using the following data structure:

```
x1a ← 2 1 ⍴ 1 0
x1b ← ⍬

x2a ← 2 2 ⍴ 1 1 0 0
x2b ← 2 1 ⍴ 1 0

x3a ← 1 2 ⍴ 1 0
x3b ← 1

q ← (x3a x3b) (x2a x2b) (x1a x1b)
```

And attempting a row reduction equivalent to the following operations:

```
output ← x3b + x3a +.× x2b + x2a +.× x1a
```

I was thinking the result would be similar to the following, but I can't get the correct rank/operations working:

```
{⍵[2] + ⍺[1] +.× ⍵[1]}/q
```

Appreciate any advice or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues:

1. You are using `⍵[1]` which will give you an enclosed element of `⍵`. Use `⊃` "pick" instead.
2. You have a typo: `⍵[2]` should use `⍺` instead, i.e. `2⊃⍺`
3. The function you reduce with, expects its right argument to be a two element vector, where it uses only the first element. It therefore needs to return such a structure for the next iteration.

Also note that the result will both be enclosed due to `/` needing to reduce the rank from 1 to 0, and furthermore will have the inserted dummy element, so we need to pick the first element of the only element, that is, `⍬ 1⊃`:

```
      x3b + x3a +.× x2b + x2a +.× x1a
3
      ⍬ 1⊃{((2⊃⍺) + (1⊃⍺) +.× (1⊃⍵)) 'dummy'}/q
3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qr8@jtgnGCo965yr4ZqYXJZZk5ucp@KSWpeZYKSSlZiSWpSrkZGanKrj7hSo4Bvj8rzBMVADqUDBSMARq2gIkDbgqDJPAYo9613BxVRjBFBhBFQCVgBQZJWFo5Kowhig2hCsGKjSGKDTk4ioEMzRAqoCimkAW0HCgQSAW0B1AezX//wfaqmD4qKu5WkPDCEg96t2lqaCtoGEIZ@sdng7jbtXUVFBPKc3NrVSv1S8EAA)

Comment: @cannadayr You're welcome. Maybe stop by the [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)?